# Following Official Flutter Tutorial Gives Me Error

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am trying to follow the Java for Android portion of [this tutorial](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab) on VSCode. When I try to run the resulting app in my Android Emulator I get this error in my Debug Console:

**Debug Console**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
E/AndroidRuntime(20503): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(20503): Process: com.example.native_code, PID: 20503
E/AndroidRuntime(20503): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.native_code/com.example.native_code.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.native_code.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~F9RZ4FuGVegZ1eIHByi9SQ==/com.example.native_code-tPV5CAJBY7lCnlthNyTpZA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~F9RZ4FuGVegZ1eIHByi9SQ==/com.example.native_code-tPV5CAJBY7lCnlthNyTpZA==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~F9RZ4FuGVegZ1eIHByi9SQ==/com.example.native_code-tPV5CAJBY7lCnlthNyTpZA==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3545)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.native_code.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~F9RZ4FuGVegZ1eIHByi9SQ==/com.example.native_code-tPV5CAJBY7lCnlthNyTpZA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~F9RZ4FuGVegZ1eIHByi9SQ==/com.example.native_code-tPV5CAJBY7lCnlthNyTpZA==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~F9RZ4FuGVegZ1eIHByi9SQ==/com.example.native_code-tPV5CAJBY7lCnlthNyTpZA==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1273)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3532)
E/AndroidRuntime(20503):    ... 12 more
```

I literally just followed the steps in the tutorial. What is going on?

Comment: Please share the code that you added from the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Whenever you create a new `Activity`, make sure to include it in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.